# angular-ui-router in iframe exit

Tags: angularjs

I'm embedding my angular project on an static html page.
It's my signup wizard, so I have multiple states.
I'd like to leave the iframe after the first state, and redirect the whole page to my URL.
any help ?

This is my iframe :

```
 <iframe src="http://0.0.0.0:9000/#/account/create/infos" width="920px" height="650px"></iframe>
```

Comment: can you post your code please?

Comment: What's the point of embedding Angular app inside an iframe? You'd better avoid it.

Comment: LFMAra, what part of the angular code would you like to see?

Comment: Sergey, we have a partner that would like to integrate our signup process, but doesn't want to code too much. I know it's not ideal, but I don't really have a say in this.